# Adding GridView dynamically in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to get a number from the user in kotlin, sync that number to rowCount and columnCount and create as many rows and columns as the number entered by the user. After creating, I want to put random numbers between 1 and 10 in the grid layout, but when the button is pressed, the grid does not add rows and columns to the layout, it stays as it is. I need your help. My Codes:

```
<GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLyt"
        style="@style/GridBorder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/gridLyt2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linearLyt">
```

this code below is the linearLayout where my buttons and editText are. I wonder if it's because of the linear layout, my button doesn't work I don't understand

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLyt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:weightSum="4">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_adet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/adet"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/piece"
            style="@style/adetTxtLayout"
            android:layout_width="83dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/adetTxt"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/adet"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/etNumber"
                style="@style/adetTxt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btncalculate"
            style="@style/ButtonGrey"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/hesapla"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_login2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/piece"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_login2"
            style="@style/ButtonGrey"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
            android:text="@string/bul"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is my MainActivity :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.btnCalculate.setOnClickListener {
            val num = binding.inpiece.text.toString().toIntOrNull() ?: return@setOnClickListener
            if (num < 1 || num > 10) return@setOnClickListener

            val textView = TextView(this)
            textView.text = "Hello, World!"
            binding.gridLyt.addView(textView)

            binding.gridLyt.apply {
                rowCount = num
                columnCount = num
                removeAllViews()

                for (i in 0 until num) {
                    for (j in 0 until num) {
                        val value = (1..10).random()
                        val textView = TextView(context).apply {
                            text = value.toString()
                            textSize = 24f
                            textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
                        }
                        addView(textView, GridLayout.LayoutParams().apply {
                            rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(i, 1f)
                            columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(j, 1f)
                            width = 0
                            height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this code but it never adds elements to the grid layout

Edit : btw, I also tried resizing the grid layout and enabled ViewBinding.

Comment: Provide images of desired output so anyone can understand from your screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to execute two loops.

Well as I understand from your question when user add any number then you need same row and column size in the grid layout.

You need to do these changes in your code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DynamicGridLayout">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextUserInput"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Number"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/buttonCalculate"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonCalculate"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calculate"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextUserInput"
        tools:context=".DynamicGridLayout" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

- Your kt file like this
- 

```
package com.example.gamazingtask

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.*
import android.widget.TextView
import com.example.gamazingtask.databinding.ActivityDynamicGridLayoutBinding

class DynamicGridLayout : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityDynamicGridLayoutBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityDynamicGridLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.buttonCalculate.setOnClickListener {

        val num = binding.editTextUserInput.text.toString().toInt()
            binding.gridLayout.apply {

                binding.gridLayout.removeAllViews()

                rowCount = num
                columnCount = num

                for (i in 0 until num * num) {
                    val value = (1 .. 10).random()
                    val textView = TextView(context).apply {
                        text = value.toString()
                        textSize = 24f
                        gravity = Gravity.CENTER

                    }
                    binding.gridLayout.addView(textView, i)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Changes is applied on the loop only and width and height you can manage now on your own.

Logic is Above in the code.

You need to change only loop because you need row and column as many as user entered number so you need to run that loop twice time of the user input number.

Comment: I put debug, it didn't even enter setOnClicker , mySetOnclicker or my button is not working im gonna edit the xml look at that please

Comment: I updated the layout file

Comment: What's your desire output provide screenshot.